# Create a range of times between two timestamps

Tags: sql, datetime, ms-access

I'm trying to create a range of times based on two timestamps.

2 examples

```
     STARTTIMESTAMP         ENDTIMESTAMP
-------------------  -------------------
22/09/2014 07:00:00  22/09/2014 15:30:00
22/09/2014 20:00:00  23/09/2014 04:00:00
```

These are start and finish times for work to be done.
There are productivity targets associated with work times (ie the second example is more productive than the first one because it occurs during a quieter part of the day).

The issue I have is that I can only get the timestamps as above (in a table called tbl_Raw_Data). To determine the "productivity" I need to expand them to show how many resources were being utilised at an given 30 min interval during the day.

Bearing in mind that each day is slightly different I need to also maintain the "cross midnight" field (ie I need to know the "day" as well as the 30 minute interval that the work time spreads across (otherwise I could just look at the numbers between 00:00 and 23:59).

What I really need is the average resources used in each 30 minute interval from midnight Monday to 23:30 Sunday (ie I would like all the other data with one column for each interval in the work time range) .

There are other fields that I need to also understand ie; Location etc... which is also used to determine productivity. There are approx 20000 records in the raw data per month.

Comment: On what platform are you developing?  Every language is a possibility here.

Comment: Hi there. MS Access. Like I said - I'm new to this.

Comment: So you have data for a large timespans and you want to divide it up evenly into half hour chunks within the boundaries of that timespan?  Are you looking at actuals or targets (you mention targets then go on to say "being utilised")?

Comment: Spot on. I actually need the "actuals" to fit into 30 min buckets.. ie if the start time is 14:15 it would fall into the 14:00 bucket. that way I can relate them to the table that has the targets.

Comment: I have tried using the DateAdd formula to create 30 min increments of the starttime, however it doesn't put them into "buckets", ie, if there is a start time of 14:05 for example...It also is limited in the number of fields it will produce.... 5 or 6 max....

Answer (score 1):

You could use a "Numbers" table to generate the intermediate Date/Time values. Your "Numbers" table would have a single column containing consecutive integers from zero to a value larger than the number of half-hour "buckets" you need to create for a given date range. So, to cover a whole month your table would have to contain numbers up to at least 31 * 48 = 1488. My [Numbers] table has 10,000 rows

```
   i
----
   0
   1
   2
   3
...
9998
9999
```

so it can handle a span of ~208 days.

Now, for an input table named [tbl_Raw_Data]

```
ID  STARTTIMESTAMP       ENDTIMESTAMP       
--  -------------------  -------------------
 1  2014-09-22 07:05:00  2014-09-22 15:30:00
 2  2014-09-22 20:00:00  2014-09-23 04:00:00
```

we can start by creating a saved query in Access named [qryRawDataDateRange] to determine the starting and ending dates for the current set of raw data

```sql
SELECT 
    MIN(DateValue(STARTTIMESTAMP)) AS FirstDate,
    MAX(DateValue(ENDTIMESTAMP)) AS LastDate
FROM tbl_Raw_Data
```

which gives us

```
FirstDate   LastDate  
----------  ----------
2014-09-22  2014-09-23
```

We can use that saved query as an input to the next saved query, [qryBucketValues], which creates all of the 30-minute "bucket" values for that range of dates

```sql
SELECT
    DateAdd("n", i * 30, FirstDate) AS BucketStart
FROM Numbers, qryRawDataDateRange
WHERE DateAdd("n", i * 30, FirstDate) < DateAdd("d", 1, LastDate)
```

returning

```
BucketStart        
-------------------
2014-09-22 00:00:00
2014-09-22 00:30:00
2014-09-22 01:00:00
2014-09-22 01:30:00
2014-09-22 02:00:00
2014-09-22 02:30:00
...
2014-09-22 22:00:00
2014-09-22 22:30:00
2014-09-22 23:00:00
2014-09-22 23:30:00
2014-09-23 00:00:00
2014-09-23 00:30:00
2014-09-23 01:00:00
2014-09-23 01:30:00
2014-09-23 02:00:00
2014-09-23 02:30:00
...
2014-09-23 22:00:00
2014-09-23 22:30:00
2014-09-23 23:00:00
2014-09-23 23:30:00
```

Now we need a query to tell us the first "bucket" for each time span in the raw data. Let's name that query [qryFirstBucket]

```sql
SELECT
    ID,
    MAX(BucketStart) AS FirstBucket,
    ENDTIMESTAMP
FROM
    tbl_Raw_Data, qryBucketValues
WHERE BucketStart <= STARTTIMESTAMP
GROUP BY ID, ENDTIMESTAMP
```

returning

```
ID  FirstBucket          ENDTIMESTAMP       
--  -------------------  -------------------
 1  2014-09-22 07:00:00  2014-09-22 15:30:00
 2  2014-09-22 20:00:00  2014-09-23 04:00:00
```

Now we can create a query named [qryBucketEntriesById] which gives us the individual bucket entries for each row (ID) in the raw data

```sql
SELECT
    ID,
    BucketStart
FROM qryFirstBucket, qryBucketValues
WHERE 
    BucketStart >= FirstBucket AND BucketStart < ENDTIMESTAMP
```

which gives us

```
ID  BucketStart        
--  -------------------
 1  2014-09-22 07:00:00
 1  2014-09-22 07:30:00
 1  2014-09-22 08:00:00
 1  2014-09-22 08:30:00
 1  2014-09-22 09:00:00
 1  2014-09-22 09:30:00
 1  2014-09-22 10:00:00
 1  2014-09-22 10:30:00
 1  2014-09-22 11:00:00
 1  2014-09-22 11:30:00
 1  2014-09-22 12:00:00
 1  2014-09-22 12:30:00
 1  2014-09-22 13:00:00
 1  2014-09-22 13:30:00
 1  2014-09-22 14:00:00
 1  2014-09-22 14:30:00
 1  2014-09-22 15:00:00
 2  2014-09-22 20:00:00
 2  2014-09-22 20:30:00
 2  2014-09-22 21:00:00
 2  2014-09-22 21:30:00
 2  2014-09-22 22:00:00
 2  2014-09-22 22:30:00
 2  2014-09-22 23:00:00
 2  2014-09-22 23:30:00
 2  2014-09-23 00:00:00
 2  2014-09-23 00:30:00
 2  2014-09-23 01:00:00
 2  2014-09-23 01:30:00
 2  2014-09-23 02:00:00
 2  2014-09-23 02:30:00
 2  2014-09-23 03:00:00
 2  2014-09-23 03:30:00
```

We can then JOIN that query to [tbl_Raw_Data] (on ID) to retrieve the rest of the raw data columns if necessary.

Comment: WOW - That is seriously awesome.

Comment: @Joey Be sure to accept this answer if it in fact provided you with a working solution.